# Unable to build flutter application after updating

Tags: flutter

I am unable to build flutter application using the following environment

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.5 <3.0.0'
```

I am getting below error

```
Error output from Xcode build:
    error: the following command failed with exit code 0 but produced no further output
    error: the following command failed with exit code 0 but produced no further output
: Error: Type 'EditableTextContextMenuBuilder' not found.
text_field.dart:558
: Error: Method 'insert' cannot be called on 'OverlayState?' because it is potentially null.
search_field.dart:244
: Error: Undefined name 'CupertinoAdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar'.
text_field.dart:442
: Error: 'EditableTextContextMenuBuilder' isn't a type.
text_field.dart:558
: Error: 'EditableTextContextMenuBuilder' isn't a type.
text_field.dart:870
: Error: No named parameter with the name 'contextMenuBuilder'.
text_field.dart:1395
: Error: A value of type 'OverlayState?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'OverlayState' because 'OverlayState?' is nullable and 'OverlayState' isn't.
tooltip.dart:170
: Error: Method 'writeState' cannot be called on 'PageStorageBucket?' because it is potentially null.
```

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue with the **dropdown_search** package

> What did I do?

Upgrade flutter by `flutter upgrade --force`

Run this command

```
flutter --version
```

if your version is under **3.3.10** then you should upgrade it.

I'll solve ;)

(If God Will)